# Read CSV URL and import selected data to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How to read a CSV coming from URL and import selected data to mysql table with PHP?

Currently I use fopen() to import the whole CSV into a table. Then I filter to my needs and echo out the variables on html.

But why import the whole CSV table, I need only a few values?

Comment: Please post your code and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV format is pure text : if you want to get only few fields, you still have to read him from start to end.

To import data from CSV to MySQL, you can generate SQL query with PHP :

```
<?php

$csvData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/yourfile.csv');
$csvDelimiter = ';';

$csvLines = str_getcsv($csvData, "\n");
foreach($csvLines as &$row) 
    $row = str_getcsv($row, $csvDelimiter);

$pairings = [
    // sql field -> csv column
    'firstname' => 0,
    'email' => 2,
    'lastname' => 1
];

$pdo = new PDO(); // Connect to your database

$linesToImport = [];
foreach ($csvLines as $line) {
    $currentLine = [];
    foreach ($pairings as $sqlField => $csvColumn) {
        $currentLine[] = isset($line[$csvColumn]) ? $pdo->quote($line[$csvColumn]) : 'null';
    }
    $linesToImport[] = implode(', ', $currentLine);
}

if (sizeof($linesToImport)) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `YourTable` (`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($pairings)) . '`) VALUES (' . implode('), (', $linesToImport) . ')';
    $pdo->exec($query);
}
```

For your specific need :

```
<?php

$csvData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/yourfile.csv');
$csvDelimiter = ';';

$csvLines = str_getcsv($csvData, "\n");
foreach($csvLines as &$row) 
    $row = str_getcsv($row, $csvDelimiter);

$pdo = new PDO(); // Connect to your database

$lastTempDate = false;
$lastTemp = false;

foreach ($csvLines as $line) {
    $date = $line[0];
    $temp = $line[1];

    if ($lastTempDate === false || $lastTempDate < $date) {
        $lastTemp = $temp;
        $lastTempDate = $date;
    }
}

if ($lastTempDate !== false) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `YourTable` (`date`, `temp`) VALUES (' . $pdo->quote($lastTempDate) . ', ' . $pdo->quote($lastTemp) . ')';
    $pdo->exec($query);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I have got the 'concept'. But still have a problem with the understanding part $csvLines = []; about  two-dimensionnal array? Is there the place for my $url (CSV URL)? Thanks for support!

Comment: I've added a small snippet to download the CSV file, and parse it :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing a CSV - I know it's me - but where I'll find the attachement?

Comment: Nah, i've added some PHP code at the beginning of my answer who downloads the CSV file of your choice :)

Comment: As I said, it was me. Got it. Thank you, I will try. Cool!

Comment: Works perfectly - Thank you!

Comment: With `$pairings`, you can configure your fields :)

Comment: May ask you a additional question?
I have only 2 fields, arrays
'TIME' => 0, (Time)
'TEMP' => 1, (Temperature)
means: every Temperature has a Time.
Now I want to make a query something like: 'INSERT only the latest value of Temperature, order by Time'.
I know how I can do it, if all entries are in the database. But I want to filter it before I write it to the database. Thank you!

Comment: By time, you mean a `datetime` sql field ? I don't find any relevance to insert only the last temperature ...

Comment: Yes the TIME string looks like this '2016-12-15 17:30:00' and want to write in the database only Latest Temperature and the Time. Something like -2.7 (Field: Temp) and 2016-12-15 17:30:00 (Field Time). I have to insert only this 2 variables (arrays), because of database design and huge CSV. I don't have needs for other fields or more values. This is why I ask :)

Comment: @Roman: Here you go, there is the specific solution for your problem :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm! Great, really :)

Comment: is it also possible to skip first row and lines with '<br>' coming from the CSV?

Comment: Why lines would contain '<br />' ?

BTW, you can skip the first line using `array_shift`.

Answer (score -1):

Just something to keep in mind about the above solution. I just implemented it and it works well. But if you are working with a very large set of data, inserting one row at a time will take a long time.

Sometimes you have no choice but to do it this way, but if you happened to insert records into an empty table, it will be much faster to dump the URL content to a temp file, parse that temp file only those columns you need (in this case it's date and temp) and then upload the file in a single shot.

```php
$SQLLoadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE `" . $input_file . "` INTO TABLE `" . $table_name . "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`date`,`temp`)";

$Recordset = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
```

Comment: Yep. Totally agree. I just happened to post an old piece of logic. I don't use "die".

Comment: I removed "die" from my example, but I am not sure what syntax error you are referring to. I copied a piece of working code. Just retested it.

Comment: `[$input file]` is an array. How can you concatenate string with an array? Why is there space in the variable name? Why are you not using prepared statements with data binding?

Comment: Oh, that. Yes, you are right. I am new to web development. There, brackets actually mean something. When I wrote requirements for developers (non-web) I always used those brackets to indicate that this is where you put an actual value. I will change it.